# Получить активных юзеров за n дней

Tags: sql

Нужна подсказка. Не могу нагуглить. Буду рад, если укажете верный путь.
Имеется таблица:

> дата  юзер_айди  действие

Требуется получить данные в формате:

> дата юзер_айди

Условие: юзер попадает в результат, если он совершил действие за последние 10 дней.
Пример: юзер_айди 57 совершил действие 1 января.
Запись в таблице:

```
дата         юзер_айди  действие
01.01.2020    57         клик
```

Значит наш результат:

```
01.01.2020 57 
02.01.2020 57 
03.01.2020 57 
04.01.2020 57 
05.01.2020 57 
06.01.2020 57 
07.01.2020 57 
08.01.2020 57 
09.01.2020 57 
10.01.2020 57
```

Comment: Хотя бы одно действие в какой-то день? Или каждый день? Почему в примере выводится 10 записей?  Покажите пример входных данных и результата.

Comment: хотя бы одно действие в какой-то день. То есть пользователь активен 9 последующих дней относительно дня действия

Comment: что-то условие в комментарии не совпадает с условием в вопросе.нужно последние 10 дней или 10 дней после указанной даты? нужно быть активным всем 10 дней или любое количество? какая СУБД?

Comment: нужно быть активным минимум 1 день, чтобы пользователь считался активным последующие 9 дней. Clickhouse

Comment: тогда мой вариант должен подойти. только посмотрите, как в кликхаус вызывается dateadd/getdate

Answer (score 0):

Синтаксис для MS SQL.
Думаю, для своей СУБД сможете подправить.
Или укажите, где именно выполняете запрос.

```
select дата, юзер_айди
from table
where дата>dateadd(dd,-10,getdate())
```

Предположим, что сегодня у нас 10 января. Нужно получить данные за предыдущие 10 дней

```
select id, date
from test
where date>dateadd(dd,-10,'20200110')
```

Результат

```
id  date
57  2020-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
57  2020-01-02 00:00:00.0000000
57  2020-01-03 00:00:00.0000000
57  2020-01-04 00:00:00.0000000
57  2020-01-05 00:00:00.0000000
57  2020-01-06 00:00:00.0000000
57  2020-01-07 00:00:00.0000000
57  2020-01-08 00:00:00.0000000
57  2020-01-09 00:00:00.0000000
57  2020-01-10 00:00:00.000000
```

Вот тут пример данных и результат работы запроса - [фиддл](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=89fe438ecb551f264d631acc569ad8af)

Comment: тут получается смещение строки? было в таблице -1 января, результат получим - 22 декабря?

Comment: Какое еще смещение? Запрос возвращает юзеров, у которых есть действие за последние 10 дней от текущей даты

Comment: Ваш запрос выдает одну строку, а мне нужно 10 строк, начиная с даты действия, заканчивая десятым днем

Comment: не понимаю, как у вас получается только 1 день. добавил пример в ответ

Comment: В моем случае таблица имеет одну запись: 01.01.2020    57.
И по Вашему запросу получается одна строка: 01.01.2020 57

Comment: так а вам что нужно? размножить эту запись на 10 дней?

Comment: Да.
Я решил эту проблему след-им способом: добавляю к этой дату еще 9 дней (1 января, 2 января...10 января), получаю вектор из этих 10 дат,  полученный вектор раскидываю отдельно по строкам в одной колонке. Способ конечно кривой, но другого пока не нашел

Comment: Создайте таблицу с календарём и сделайте к ней join